# VB.Net: Acumulador no pasa de una suma

Tags: vb.net

Hice un programa de multiplicaciones, y al `score` lo puse que se acumule de 5 en 5, sin embargo no pasa de 10. ¿En qué está fallando mi programa?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim mi_Num1 As Integer
    Dim mi_Num2 As Integer
    Dim mi_Result As Integer
    Dim mi_score As Integer
    Dim mi_Puntaje As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pbxObjeto.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\1.png")
        pbxObjeto3.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\9.1.png")
        pbxObjeto2.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\6.png")
        pbxObjeto4.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\7.png")
        pbxObjeto5.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\7.png")
        pbxObjeto6.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\7.png")
        pbxIgual.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\igual.png")
        pbxX.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\por.png")
        pbxCoin.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\coin.png")

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnJugar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJugar.Click
        Dim Random As New Random()
        txtNumero1.Text = Random.Next(1, 10)
        txtNumero2.Text = Random.Next(1, 11)
        txtResultado.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
        If Val(txtResultado.Text) > 0 Then
            mi_Num1 = txtNumero1.Text
            mi_Num2 = txtNumero2.Text
            mi_Result = txtNumero1.Text * txtNumero2.Text
            If txtResultado.Text() = mi_Result Then

                txtScore.Text = mi_score
                pbxCarita.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\feliz.png")

                Dim mi_mensaje = "¡Correcto," + " " + "Sigue así!"
                mi_score = 5
                lblMensaje.Visible = True
                lblMensaje.Text = mi_mensaje
                txtNumero1.Text = ""
                txtNumero2.Text = ""
                txtResultado.Text = ""
                txtScore.Text = (CInt(txtScore.Text) + 5)

            Else
                Dim mi_mensaje2 = "Sigue participando"
                pbxCarita.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\triste.png")
                lblMensaje.Text = mi_mensaje2

                Call Limpia_Variables()

            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Debe teclear un valor numerico antes de continuar")
            txtResultado.Focus()
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub Limpia_Variables()
        txtScore.Text = mi_score
        mi_Puntaje = 0
        txtScore.Text = "0"
        txtNumero1.Text = 0
        txtNumero2.Text = 0
        txtResultado.Text = ""

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnSalir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSalir.Click
        If MsgBox("¿Està seguro de salir del juego?)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Dingo Multiplicación") = vbYes Then
            End
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtResultado_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtResultado.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu problema esta aqui

```
        ------>txtScore.Text = mi_score 
                pbxCarita.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\feliz.png")

                Dim mi_mensaje = "¡Correcto," + " " + "Sigue así!"
         ------->mi_score = 5 
                lblMensaje.Visible = True
                lblMensaje.Text = mi_mensaje
                txtNumero1.Text = ""
                txtNumero2.Text = ""
                txtResultado.Text = ""
                txtScore.Text = (CInt(txtScore.Text) + 5)
```

cada vez que preciones el boton mi_score sera 5 anque al ultimo lo sumes si vuelves a entrar  lo va a reiniciar a 5 y se vuelve a sumar 5 y por eso te da siempre 10

seria algo asi.

```
                txtScore.Text = mi_score 
                pbxCarita.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\feliz.png")

                Dim mi_mensaje = "¡Correcto," + " " + "Sigue así!"

                lblMensaje.Visible = True
                lblMensaje.Text = mi_mensaje
                txtNumero1.Text = ""
                txtNumero2.Text = ""
                txtResultado.Text = ""
                mi_score += 5
                txtScore.Text = mi_score.tostring()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores de sintaxis en la caja de MsgBox en constantes, además de tener algunos fallos corregidos en el siguiente código...

```html
Public Class Form1
    Dim mi_Num1 As Integer
    Dim mi_Num2 As Integer
    Dim mi_Result As Long
    Dim mi_score As Integer
    Dim mi_Puntaje As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pbxObjeto.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\1.png")
        pbxObjeto3.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\9.1.png")
        pbxObjeto2.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\6.png")
        pbxObjeto4.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\7.png")
        pbxObjeto5.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\7.png")
        pbxObjeto6.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\7.png")
        pbxIgual.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\igual.png")
        pbxX.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\por.png")
        pbxCoin.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\coin.png")

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnJugar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJugar.Click
        Dim Random As New Random()
        txtNumero1.Text = Random.Next(1, 10)
        txtNumero2.Text = Random.Next(1, 11)
        txtResultado.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
        If CInt(txtResultado.Text) > 0 Then
            mi_Num1 = CInt(txtNumero1.Text)
            mi_Num2 = CInt(txtNumero2.Text)
            mi_Result = mi_Num1 * mi_Num2
            If CLng(txtResultado.Text) = mi_Result Then

                txtScore.Text = mi_score
                pbxCarita.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\feliz.png")

                Dim mi_mensaje As String = "¡Correcto," + " " + "Sigue así!"
                mi_score = 5
                lblMensaje.Visible = True
                lblMensaje.Text = mi_mensaje
                txtNumero1.Text = ""
                txtNumero2.Text = ""
                txtResultado.Text = ""
                txtScore.Text = (CInt(txtScore.Text) + 5)

            Else
                Dim mi_mensaje2 = "Sigue participando"
                pbxCarita.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1713M\triste.png")
                lblMensaje.Text = mi_mensaje2

                Limpia_Variables()

            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Debe teclear un valor numerico antes de continuar")
            txtResultado.Focus()
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub Limpia_Variables()
        txtScore.Text = mi_score
        mi_Puntaje = 0
        txtScore.Text = "0"
        txtNumero1.Text = 0
        txtNumero2.Text = 0
        txtResultado.Text = ""

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnSalir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSalir.Click
        If MsgBox("¿Està seguro de salir del juego?)", vbYesNo, "Dingo Multiplicación") = vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtResultado_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtResultado.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```